# jquery conflict between 2 versions (using bootstrap template) yii2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, templates, yii2, assets

Im using a template in my site. The template is using jquery v1.7.1 and bootstrap v3.0.0 in the index page and for example, the alumno home (localhost:8080/sie/web/index.php?r=site/alumno).

The problem is when I log in and try to navigate through the site. The site has lots of modals and everytime I navigate through a page that has a modal, the menu doesn’t display or disappears. And when logged in, menu disappears in index.

Here are some images:

[Index not logged in OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFhvJ.jpg)

[Loggin not logged in OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiwbi.png)

[Alumno Home not showing the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlGy3.png)

[Going back to index, logged in, not showing the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkM3k.jpg)

I use assets to register my bootstrap and jquery files in index and main layouts as seen below:

IndexAsset.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main application asset bundle.
 *
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class IndexAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/index/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'css/index/camera.css',
        'css/index/font-awesome.min.css',
        'css/index/isotope.css',
        'css/index/style.css',
        'css/index/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/index/slider.js',
        'js/index/bootstrap.min.js',
        'js/index/google-map.js',
        'js/index/html5shiv.js',
        'js/index/jquery.cslider.js',
        'js/index/jquery.isotope.min.js',
        'js/index/respond.min.js',
        'js/index/modernizr-latest.js',
        'js/index/jquery.min.js',
        'js/index/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
        'js/index/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js',
        'js/index/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
        'js/index/camera.min.js',
        'js/index/custom.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

AppAsset.php

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/main/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'css/main/site.css',
        'css/main/style.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/main/bootstrap.min.js',
        'js/main/jquery.min.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',        
    ];
}
```

index.php layout

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use app\widgets\Alert;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\IndexAsset;
use app\models\User;

IndexAsset::register($this);

?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title)?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Button for smallest screens -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Techro HTML5 template"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right mainNav">
                                    <?php if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { ?>
                    <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Inicio', ['index'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Acerca', ['about'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Contacto', ['contact'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Login', ['login'])?></li>
                                    <?php } else if (User::isUserDirector (Yii::$app->user->identity->id))
                    { ?>
                                        <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Calendario', ['calendario/index'])?></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Área Docente <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Profesores', ['profesor/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Asignatura', ['asignatura/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cursos', ['curso/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Libro de Clases <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Alumnos', ['alumno/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Notas', ['nota/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Apoderados', ['apoderado/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cuenta <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Perfil('.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.')', ['site/director'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cerrar Sesión', ['site/logout'], ['data-method' => 'post'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>    

<div class="wrap">   
    <div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= Alert::widget() ?>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">

        <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="footerbottom">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="footerwidget">
        <h4>
          Course Categories
        </h4>
        <div class="menu-course">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">
                List of Technology 
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                List of Business
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                List of Photography
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
               List of Language
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="footerwidget">
        <h4>
          Products Categories
        </h4>
        <div class="menu-course">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li> <a href="#">
                Individual Plans  </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                Business Plans
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                Free Trial
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                Academic
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="footerwidget">
        <h4>
          Browse by Categories
        </h4>
        <div class="menu-course">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">
                All Courses
              </a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">
                All Instructors
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                All Members
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                All Groups
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"> 
                <div class="footerwidget"> 
                         <h4>Contact</h4> 
                        <p>Lorem reksi this dummy text unde omnis iste natus error sit volupum</p>
            <div class="contact-info"> 
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Kerniles 416  - United Kingdom<br>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+00 123 156 711 <br>
             <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> youremail@email.com
              </div> 
                </div><!-- end widget --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            <div class="social text-center">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--CLEAR FLOATS-->
        </div>
        <div class="footer2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="simplenav">
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a> | 
                                <a href="about.html">About</a> |
                                <a href="courses.html">Courses</a> |
                                <a href="price.html">Price</a> |
                                <a href="videos.html">Videos</a> |
                                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="text-right">
                                Copyright &copy; 2014. Template by <a href="http://webthemez.com/" rel="develop">WebThemez.com</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /row of panels -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

main.php layout

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use app\widgets\Alert;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;
use app\models\User;

AppAsset::register($this);

?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title)?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Button for smallest screens -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Techro HTML5 template"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right mainNav">
                                    <?php if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { ?>
                    <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Inicio', ['index'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Acerca', ['about'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Contacto', ['contact'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Login', ['login'])?></li>
                                    <?php } else if (User::isUserDirector (Yii::$app->user->identity->id))
                    { ?>
                                        <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Calendario', ['calendario/index'])?></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Área Docente <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Profesores', ['profesor/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Asignatura', ['asignatura/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cursos', ['curso/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Libro de Clases <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Alumnos', ['alumno/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Notas', ['nota/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Apoderados', ['apoderado/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cuenta <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Perfil('.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.')', ['site/director'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cerrar Sesión', ['site/logout'], ['data-method' => 'post'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>    
    <header id="head" class="secondary">
            <div class="container">
                    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eliras scele!</p>
                </div>
    </header>
<div class="wrap">   
    <div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= Alert::widget() ?>
            <?= $content ?>

    </div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">

        <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="footerbottom">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="footerwidget">
        <h4>
          Course Categories
        </h4>
        <div class="menu-course">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">
                List of Technology 
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                List of Business
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                List of Photography
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
               List of Language
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="footerwidget">
        <h4>
          Products Categories
        </h4>
        <div class="menu-course">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li> <a href="#">
                Individual Plans  </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                Business Plans
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                Free Trial
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                Academic
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="footerwidget">
        <h4>
          Browse by Categories
        </h4>
        <div class="menu-course">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">
                All Courses
              </a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">
                All Instructors
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                All Members
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                All Groups
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"> 
                <div class="footerwidget"> 
                         <h4>Contact</h4> 
                        <p>Lorem reksi this dummy text unde omnis iste natus error sit volupum</p>
            <div class="contact-info"> 
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Kerniles 416  - United Kingdom<br>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+00 123 156 711 <br>
             <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> youremail@email.com
              </div> 
                </div><!-- end widget --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            <div class="social text-center">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--CLEAR FLOATS-->
        </div>
        <div class="footer2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="simplenav">
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a> | 
                                <a href="about.html">About</a> |
                                <a href="courses.html">Courses</a> |
                                <a href="price.html">Price</a> |
                                <a href="videos.html">Videos</a> |
                                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="text-right">
                                Copyright &copy; 2014. Template by <a href="http://webthemez.com/" rel="develop">WebThemez.com</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /row of panels -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

I found this error in index.php related to yii’s Bootstrap’s v3.4.1 jquery

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4
    at bootstrap.js:15
    at bootstrap.js:17
```

and this one related to function modal and template’s jquery v1.7.1 in alumno home

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).modal is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.php?r=site%2Falumno:217)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.B (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Any thoughts on how I can use both, mine and yii’s jquery versions?
Any help would be appreciated
I’m very confused

Comment: Most solutions (usually involving aliasing) will require more effort than just eliminating the old version. Why can't you modify your template?

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean. Im new to jquery.

Comment: Why can't you modify your template to remove the line of code that loads the (really) old version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days I finally solved it! It wasn’t jQuery nor Bootstrap. It was my layout.
I wasn’t printing the menu for certain users. Stupid me.

Here’s the code.

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use app\widgets\Alert;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;
use app\models\User;

AppAsset::register($this);

?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title)?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Button for smallest screens -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Techro HTML5 template"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right mainNav">
                                    <?php if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { ?>
                    <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Inicio', ['index'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Acerca', ['about'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Contacto', ['contact'])?></li>
                    <li><?=Html::a('Login', ['login'])?></li>
                                    <?php } else if (User::isUserDirector (Yii::$app->user->identity->id)){ ?>
                                        <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Calendario', ['calendario/index'])?></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Área Docente <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Profesores', ['profesor/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Asignatura', ['asignatura/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cursos', ['curso/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Libro de Clases <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Alumnos', ['alumno/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Notas', ['nota/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Apoderados', ['apoderado/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cuenta <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Perfil('.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.')', ['site/director'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cerrar Sesión', ['site/logout'], ['data-method' => 'post'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <?php } else if (User::isUserProfesor (Yii::$app->user->identity->id)){?>
                                        <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Calendario', ['calendario/index'])?></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Área Docente <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Profesores', ['profesor/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Asignatura', ['asignatura/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cursos', ['curso/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Libro de Clases <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Alumnos', ['alumno/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Notas', ['nota/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Apoderados', ['apoderado/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cuenta <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Perfil('.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.')', ['site/profesor'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cerrar Sesión', ['site/logout'], ['data-method' => 'post'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <?php } else if (User::isUserAlumno (Yii::$app->user->identity->id)){?>
                                        <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Calendario', ['calendario/index'])?></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Área Docente <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Profesores', ['profesor/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Asignatura', ['asignatura/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cursos', ['curso/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Libro de Clases <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Alumnos', ['alumno/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Notas', ['nota/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Apoderados', ['apoderado/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cuenta <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Perfil('.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.')', ['site/alumno'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cerrar Sesión', ['site/logout'], ['data-method' => 'post'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <?php } else if (User::isUserApoderado (Yii::$app->user->identity->id)){?>
                                        <li class="active"><?=Html::a('Calendario', ['calendario/index'])?></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Área Docente <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Profesores', ['profesor/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Asignatura', ['asignatura/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cursos', ['curso/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Libro de Clases <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Alumnos', ['alumno/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Notas', ['nota/index'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Apoderados', ['apoderado/index'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cuenta <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?=Html::a('Perfil('.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.')', ['site/apoderado'])?></li>
                                                        <li><?=Html::a('Cerrar Sesión', ['site/logout'], ['data-method' => 'post'])?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>    
    <header id="head" class="secondary">
            <div class="container">
                    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eliras scele!</p>
                </div>
    </header>
<div class="wrap">   
    <div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= Alert::widget() ?>
            <?= $content ?>

    </div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
        <div class="footer2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="simplenav">
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a> | 
                                <a href="about.html">About</a> |
                                <a href="courses.html">Courses</a> |
                                <a href="price.html">Price</a> |
                                <a href="videos.html">Videos</a> |
                                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="text-right">
                                Copyright &copy; 2014. Template by <a href="http://webthemez.com/" rel="develop">WebThemez.com</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /row of panels -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```